# How to get the current element height?

Tags: d3.js

So that I can transition the bars in a bar chart smoothly I need to set the height before I call `transition()`.

When the chart first renders the bars animate up from the bottom of the chart as required:

```
    chart.svg.selectAll('.bar')
        .attr('y', chart.options.height)
        .attr('x', function (d) {
            return chart.xScale(d.title);
        })
        .attr('width', chart.xScale.rangeBand())
        .attr('height', function () {
            return 0;
        })
        .transition()
        .attr('y', function (d) {
            return chart.yScale(d.score);
        })
        .attr('height', function (d) {
            return chart.options.height - chart.yScale(d.score);
        });
```

However, when I change the data I don't want to set the height back to `0`. Instead I need to set the height to the current height of the rectangle. How can I access this from the `attr` function?

```
        .attr('height', function () {
            return 0; // how do I get the current height
        })
```

When I log `this` I have access to the DOM element but not sure where to go from there. I tried `d3.select(this).attr('height')` but it always returns null.

Comment: If the height is already set, you don't need to re-set it. With new data, just add `.transition().attr("height", ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LarsKotthoff is hinting at in his comment, just break apart your initial draw from your update:

```
// intial draw of bars
node
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "myBars")
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr('y', config.height)
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
  .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
  .attr('height', function() {
    return 0;
  });
```

Then fire the update to transition the bars from their current position:

```
function update() {
  node = svg
    .selectAll(".myBars")
    .data(data);
  node
    .transition()
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return yScale(d);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return config.height - yScale(d);
    });
}
```

Here's the most minimal [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QGlCoB?p=preview) I could code up.

[image]